# I'm looking to return an object linked to a max value of a single row in Python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I'm new to Python, and I'm struggling with extracting the data linked to a max value.

Here's my code

```py
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import statistics  
import scipy  
from pandas import read_csv  
filename = 'airbnb.csv'  
airbnb = pd.read_csv("./airbnb.csv")  
airbnb.head()  
table_quartier =airbnb.groupby(['Arrondissement','Quartier']).agg({'Nombre avis': "sum"})  
arrondissement_plus = table_quartier.loc[table_quartier['Nombre avis'].idxmax()]  
arrondissement_plus.reset_index()  

**I'm looking to return 'Arrondissement' as the answer, how do I extract this info from the index found in 'arrondissement_plus'**
```

Comment: paste the actual data, not images of the data please!

Comment: Not even sure on how to paste the data...that's how beginner I am :)